# Reportportal properties file in gradle multi project set up

Tags: reportportal

I am using reportportal.io for integrated reporting. I was able to successfully integrate with Junit tests I am running for a single gradle project. As the documentation indicated, I placed the reportportal.properties file along with logback.xml in resources folder and update build.gradle file.

But in a multi gradle project, when I place the properties file and logback.xml file in resources folder of project folder where test task is defined, reportportal agent does not seem to be invoked.

Any pointers about right approach to integrate Junit test reporting for multi project gradle and reportportal is highly appreciated.

Comment: Integration can't find property file? Or integration agent just don't start within multiply projects?

Comment: it does not start within multi project.